# Is there a way to display any app in "windowed fullscreen mode"?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to display any app (that has a fullscreen mode) in "windowed fullscreen mode"? What I'm after is to be able to "maximize" an app and move/resize it. Take VLC for example. If I maximize a video, all Windows "decorations" disappear and I'm left with a clean UI. This is almost what I'm after, except now I can't move/resize the window.

My browser has a pop out video feature that almost works. Any video that I have tried is resizable/movable (Netflix, YouTube, HBO,...), except all video controls are lost.
My first thought was a virtual machine. I have only used VirtualBox and when I did, I could not find any settings for hiding menus/borders. But if there is a way with a VM that's fine, if I could maximize the app inside the VM's window and also hide the VM, that is.

I found [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEwdu2F_Rdw&t=80s) that demonstrates how my browser's pop out video functions. Note that I've used videos in all examples, but what I'm after should work for any and all apps that have a fullscreen mode.

The ability to move the window is not a necessity as I have an AutoHotkey script for that.

Clarification:

I want the window to be a maximum of 1/4 of screen size.

Comment: Does this work: Create a Windows shortcut to start your app from, and set it as ‘Run Maximized’ ?

Comment: @knb That seems to just open the window as maximized. I see no way of changing its size.

Comment: Maximised is inflexible on Windows. Try to move it, the window will Restore. Only way I can see round it is to manually drag the corners out to fill the screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin I want the window to be a maximum of 1/4 of screen size, so that solution would not work. I'll edit the question to make this clear.